# How to keep two TextInputLayouts on single line consistent width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textinputlayout

I have two `TextInputLayout` on a single line. They take half of the screen each when rendered:
[image]

But if i type alot of text in one and less in the other, their width changes and one of them gets smooshed:

[image]

How do i keep them of the same ratio that they started with, no matter how much text were entered?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use `android:layout_wight="1"` for both `TextInputLayout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `android:layout_width="0dp"`for the TextInputLayout should do the trick.

Also you should use `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText` instead of `EditText`.